# Set UITableViewCell frame with margins in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to make a UITableViewCell with left and right margins/insets. I have made this in the past with Objective-C using the following code:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x += 25;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * 25;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

This code doesn't directly translate to Swift, as now I have to override the public frame variable, but placing this code in the setter of that variable has no effect. How would I get the margins to appear using this, or a similar technique in Swift?

This is the Swift that I have attempted:

```
private var otherFrame: CGRect = CGRectZero
override public var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return otherFrame
    }
    set {
        otherFrame = frame
        otherFrame.origin.x += 25
        otherFrame.size.width -= 2 * 25
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you put it in the getter? This is an override of the setter.

Comment: oops I meant setter, I edited the question

Comment: Update your question with your attempted Swift code and clearly explain what issue you are having with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct translation of the Objective-C code would be:

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set {
        var frame = newValue
        frame.origin.x += 25
        frame.size.width -= 2 * 25

        super.frame = frame
    }
}
```

There's no need for the additional property. You use the implicit value `newValue` in the setter.

Comment: Thank You! I wasted 2 full days before I found this. Works like a charm!

Comment: if you just minus the width, it seems that some label text would be truncated. How to adjust the height to fix this issue?

Comment: Is there also a similar way to set the section header with?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell you cell to not follow the margins of the tableView this way:

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
```

And set the margins of your cell this way:

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 25, bottom: 0, right: 25)
```

Comment: Would you put this in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I would, except if you have a custom class for your cell. In that case maybe it would work from there.

Comment: Where would you put it in a custom class? layoutSubviews?

Comment: in awakeFromNib()