# iOS - Left and right margin for UITableViewCells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a dynamic table view in grouped style and different custom cells in separate nibs, which then I register in viewDidLoad and add them to the tableview accordingly. In story board I added a uiview under the prototype cell to be my footer inside there's a button. Now because my cells have borders I want to have a left and right margin , but not for the whole tableView , only for the cells . I did use this code :

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10);
```

but doing this , my footer doesn't have the width of the screen anymore.

I looked in the web and found some people use this:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16))
    }
}
```

but this doesn't do anything.

Note that viewForHeaderinSection and viewForFooterInSection are used on my application. Any suggestions please. Thank you

Comment: you can use method for set contentInset.

Comment: import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16))
    }
}

you won’t see the applied margin because under the content view there is a background view of the table cell. So it prevents the margin because it is by default white, so it should be transparent

Comment: try setting the background color of cell to transparent(clear color)

Comment: @ChiragKothiya you mean like this :  `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)` . I did do that but as I said the margin is also applied to the footer and I don't want that

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan I did that still nothing happens :(

Comment: Could you share your code? where did you make the cell transparent ?

Comment: `override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }`

Comment: That looks good, could you share your cellforrowatindexpath code? and also try clearing the background in the cellforrowatindexpath method

Comment: OMG I am stupid :D . I got it working thank you so much and sorry for waisting your time

Comment: Good to hear that, thumbsup

Answer (score 2):

For future reference this is how I fixed it   :

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set {
        var frame = newValue
        frame.origin.x += 25
        frame.size.width -= 2 * 25

        super.frame = frame
    }
}
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094806